# android using fragment with

Tags: android, fragment, savestate

In my android application i'm using sliding menu, thats why all my content is in fragments, which i'm changing and show them in one activity in FrameLayout.
The problem is that i have fragments with data that are loaded from internet, listview and others, and if i run my app listview will be filled by data, then if i go to another fragment and then push back button on my phone, we will return to fragment with that listview, but it will again download data, initialize adapter and add it to listview.

How can i save all this data, and show it again when i go to this fragment from another ?

Answer (score 1):

Where are you reading the data in Fragments? Detaching the fragments from activity should not kill the whole fragment but only the UI part - see fragment lifecycle, calls that happen are between onCreateView and onDestroyView. If you read the data only in onCreate and onCreateView just to inflate the layout and populate it everything should be fine.

Comment: in onActivityCreated() i'm initialize my listview and execute my inner class that extends AsynkTask, it download all data and in onPostExecute() method add adapter to listview

Comment: That's the issue. You should create and launch the task in onCreate because that will not be called multiple times unlike onActivityCreated(). onCreateView will initialize the listview and populate it.

Answer (score 0):

Cache your data in database and download only if your cache is empty or outdated (i.e. keep download timestamp and re-download when X hours/days passed if that is needed)